# Delete cells from specific columns using a specific range

Tags: excel, vbscript

I am trying to write a VBScript to delete the contents of cells in columns `F, S` and `T` from row `1492` to `17910`. I only know how to delete an entire row using `.Rows(X).EntireRow.Delete` My idea was just loop through the rows and delete the data in the cells which are in that range, but I don't know how to delete contents in one specific cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Range()` function to specify your three ranges and call the `Clear` method on each range to remove all values/formatting/etc.

Assuming your Excel application variable is named `objExcel` and your range is located on your active sheet, you could use the following:

```
With objExcel.ActiveSheet
    .Range("F1492:F17910").Clear
    .Range("S1492:S17910").Clear
    .Range("T1492:T17910").Clear
End With
```

Since `Range()` can accept multiple ranges, you could even do this in a single call:

```
objExcel.ActiveSheet.Range("F1492:F17910,S1492:S17910,T1492:T17910").Clear
```

If you just want to clear the contents but keep the formatting, use `ClearContents` instead.

Comment: From a running time stance, would it be faster to do it how you did or just loop through that range and clear the entire row?

Comment: This will be considerably faster than using any type of loop. If you're asking about the speed between clearing _just_ columns `F`, `S`, and `T` versus clearing the entire row, it could be a trade-off.